# Why the relationship $v_p v_g = c^2$ (phase velocity multiply group velocity equals lightspeed squared) exists in waveguide structures?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, waveguide, phase-velocity

What’s the reason that the relationship of [de Broglie hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave)(hypothesis-->relations) will hold in Waveguide structures?

Comment: The fact that $v_g v_p = c^2$ isn't related to the de Broglie hypothesis. Or at least I can't see how it is related. This result follows from purely classical electrodynamics.

Comment: Really? It isn't related to de Broglie hypothesis, but is it related to de Broglie relations? And can you explain why it holds in waveguide structures ?

Comment: Hint: The relation $c^2~=~v_pv_g  ~=~ \frac{E}{p} \frac{\partial E}{\partial p}~=~ \frac{\partial (E^2)}{\partial (p^2)}$ follows from Pythagoras formula $E^2~=~(pc)^2 + (mc^2)^2 $ in SR.

Comment: @JohnRennie Agreed. It is purely classical wave theory, even though it is encountered in QM cases, too, as in quantum free particles, whose stationary states' wavefunctions are normalised by forcing them into groups (or wave packets) of closely spaced $k$ values, using similar Fourier procedure as in the classical case for a narrow band signal propagating down the guide or transmission line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fact exists in classical wave theory. The phase velocity is $v_{p}=\omega/\beta$, whereas the group velocity is $v_{g}=d\omega/d\beta$ (i.e. velocity of a narrow band signal, calculated from the dispersion relation $\omega=\omega(\beta)$ for your waveguide), where $\omega$ is the angular frequency of the propagating wave and $\beta$ is its (guided) propagation constant (same as the wavenumber, $k$, in lossless guides).  Now, in a typical waveguide, you have $\beta$ derived (say as eigenvalue of the Helmholtz wave equation and given boundary conditions) to be $\beta=\sqrt{k^{2}_{0}-k^{2}_{c}}$, where $k_{0}=\omega/c$ is the free-space wavenumber (if waveguide weren't there) and $k^{2}_{c}$ is a geomery-based cutoff wavenumber (constant), calculated based on the particular boundary conditions of the structure. Therefore, you can see that

$$ \frac{d\beta}{d\omega}=\frac{2\omega/c^{2}}{2\sqrt{(\omega/c)^{2}-k^{2}_{0}}}=\frac{\omega}{c^{2}\beta}\Rightarrow v_{p}v_{g}=\frac{\omega}{\beta}\frac{c^{2}\beta}{\omega}=c^{2}.$$

As energy propagates down the waveguide at the group velocity, which may be slower than light in such structures, you can now see easily why the phase velocity becomes higher than the speed of light ($v_{g}\leq c\leq v_{p}$, with $c$ as their geometric mean).

Answer (score -1):

Wkt,
Vp=w/k=E/p------(1)
Vg=dw/dk
w=2πf=2πE/h
k=2π/(wavelength)=2πp/h
dw=2πdE/h
dk=2πdp/h
dw/dk=Vg
=>Vg=dE/dp=d(pc)/dp=c------(2)
Now,
(1)×(2) => VgVp=E/p × c = mc²/mc × c [using Einstein's energy mass eqn and momentum= mass × velocity (speed of light in this case)
VgVp=c²
That's your result!

Comment: Welcome to SE. As it is, this answer is unreadable. Please use the tools (MathJax) provided by this site to enhance its quality. Thank you.